# How to get style from div into js?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a div (the styles are made by another js script). I want to get the values of `--rows` and `--columns` into another JS file. When I output them to the console it just outputs "". What is wrong?

```js
const rowscolumns = document.getElementById('sliderh')

var rows = rowscolumns.style.getPropertyValue("--rows")
var columns = rowscolumns.style.getPropertyValue("--columns")

console.log(rows)
```

```html
<div id="sliderh" class="slider_box" style="--relative_pos:46.5px; --rows:7; --columns:5;">
  ...
</div>
```

Ok here is the other js script that ads the style elements:

```
function relcalch() {
let relPos2 = (valueh * Stepsh) / hWidth * 100
elementh.style.setProperty("--relative_pos",`${relPos2}%`)
elementh.style.setProperty("--rows",`${valueh + 3}`)
elementh.style.setProperty("--columns",`${valuew + 3}`)
texth.innerHTML = valueh +3
}
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if the problem was one of timing. You said "the styles are made by another js script" but didn't provide a [mcve] demonstrating that. Likely you are trying to read the values **before** they've been set by the other script.

Comment: --rows and --columns as far as I know aren't styles. So not sure why it would work. Why not just get the whole attribute of 'style' and split it by semicolons

Comment: Oh yeah, that might be the problem, is there a way to run the second script after the values are set?

Comment: @luuf — Probably. Depends on how the code that sets them works. (See [ask]; in particular the part about providing a [mcve]).

Comment: Oh sorry, i set them with setProperty

Comment: But you did that *at a time* in response to *something* (again, see [mcve])

Comment: Re edit: Click the "Run code snippet" button. Does that many any sense at all? You've put the other JS function in the HTML box instead of the JavaScript box. You also haven't written any code that would call it, so it still isn't possible to understand what triggers it (and thus when the other code needs to run).

Comment: How do I do that, I'm new to stack overflow, and for some reason when trying to edit, ´´´ wasn't there anymore, just something similar to <start of snippet> and <end of snippet> when trying to replicate that it didn't work

Comment: Ok I don't get it, how do you close a discussion?

Comment: Since people have posted answers which have been upvoted (even though they are wrong) you can't delete the question. The community has failed to vote to close your question. I think the only thing you can do is hit **Flag** and bring it to the attention of the moderators.

Comment: Update: I have figured out my stupidity and will (if possible) make a followup answer to this post

Answer (score 0):

> When I output them to the console it just outputs "".

if you check the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/getPropertyValue) here as it says:

> Return Value
>
> A string containing the value of the property. If not set, returns the empty string.

It shows your property as String in quotes "". Nothing is wrong.

Comment: They said it outputs **just** `""` (as opposed to `"7"`) … but the live demo doesn't behave that way.

Comment: Yeah I'm confused, the console outputs something (when inspecting the website) but it doesn't output a number, not even a letter. But for some reason it works on stack overflow?

Comment: @luuf — The OP hasn't provided a real [mcve]; the question should be closed using the community moderation process (or they should fix the question). It can't be reasonably answered.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out that I was doing a really stupid thing in the first place:
My code now is using data, not style (for rows and columns):

First the html:

```
<div id="sliderh" class="slider_box" data-rows="5" data-columns="6">
   <div class="slider_ind"></div>
</div>
```

Now setting the data:

```
function relcalch() {
    let relPos2 = (valueh * Stepsh) / hWidth * 100
    elementh.style.setProperty("--relative_pos",`${relPos2}%`)
    elementh.dataset.rows = `${valueh + 3}`
    elementh.dataset.columns = `${valuew + 3}`
    texth.innerHTML = valueh +3
}
```

And then retrieving said data in another js file (it outputs when a button is pressed):

```
const button = document.querySelectorAll('.buttons')
const rowscolumns = document.getElementById('sliderh')

function update() {
    console.log(rowscolumns.dataset.rows)
    console.log(rowscolumns.dataset.columns)
}

button.forEach(item => {
    item.addEventListener("click", update);
})
```